# NRF24l01+ Arduino to Raspberry - Receving working randomly

Tags: pi-3, python, arduino, nrf24l01

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (RF24 lib) and Arduino Mega (RF24 lib)
I have cleaned the pins and soldered a 10 uF capacitor between vcc & gnd

The distance between the two modules has no effect.

I think this screenshot says everything (pingpair_dyn.py, one of RF24 lib examples)

[pingpair_dyn.py](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/examples/pingpair_dyn/pingpair_dyn.ino)
[pingpair_dyn.ino](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/examples_linux/pingpair_dyn.py)

arduino => role_pong_back 
raspberry pi => role_ping_out

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help ! :)

Comment: No one can provide insight here unless you post the relevant code.

Comment: "Posting relevant code..." does not mean a link.  However, seeing as how you've found a solution in context, I don't think there is much here you can do to make the question more widely relevant.  Obviously this is about experimenting and observing -- beyond that no one actually needs to issue a command to send a radio message, then in 0 time initialize something to read the same radio message (or response to same) from a component which *is wired into the same device*.  In other words, you might as well leave this and forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

Added a delay (>20ms) before radio.write() (arduino side) solved the issue.

radio.startListening() seems to be very slow in python and as a result, the pi miss the reply (most of the time).

Comment: If Its not a complete answer, you can just edit your question.